# How to use WITH XMLNAMESPACES for many select statements?

Tags: sql-server-2008, xml-namespaces

I use the `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` statement in SQL Server 2008 to define some namespaces in the form of

```
 ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://bla' AS nsBlub)
```

And then I would like to execute multiple(!) select statements all making use of the above defined `nsBlub` namespace.

But only the first select statement under the above `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` statement benefits from the namespace declaration, so I need to write the same `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` statement before every select statement at the moment...

What am I missing - how do I define a namespace with `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` "globally"?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that, unfortunately.

The `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` clause is good for one statement only. It's almost like a "header" attribute for your next statement - you cannot extend that over more than one statement.

For the next one, you have to repeat the `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` again.

There's no workaround for this, as far as I know.